# Why does the getUTCMinutes() method shows different minutes for different locations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Why does the getUTCMinutes() method show the wrong time - different minutes for different locations? I am getting data from Openweather API and then want to show local date and time for different cities. Everything works fine but the minutes are not the same depending on which city I enter in my app it shows differently.

Code example:

```
const localMinutes = new Date((data.dt + data.timezone) * 1000).getUTCMinutes()
```

JSON:

```
                          

{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 10.99,
    "lat": 44.34
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 501,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "moderate rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 298.48,
    "feels_like": 298.74,
    "temp_min": 297.56,
    "temp_max": 300.05,
    "pressure": 1015,
    "humidity": 64,
    "sea_level": 1015,
    "grnd_level": 933
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.62,
    "deg": 349,
    "gust": 1.18
  },
  "rain": {
    "1h": 3.16
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 100
  },
  "dt": 1661870592,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2075663,
    "country": "IT",
    "sunrise": 1661834187,
    "sunset": 1661882248
  },
  "timezone": 7200,
  "id": 3163858,
  "name": "Zocca",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: The same local time in different timezones _is_ a different UTC time. It's not clear what `data` is or what you think React/JSX has to do with this - give a [mre].

Comment: Added more description of the problem and JSON file.

Comment: And what do you mean _"different minutes for different locations"_? You've only shown _one_ location. `new Date(data.dt * 1_000)` will already give you the user's local time (e.g. for me it's `Tue Aug 30 2022 15:43:12 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`), it doesn't make sense to add the offset to a _timestamp_, which is always UTC (that the location is two hours ahead of UTC doesn't make it two hours later _in UK time_, particularly as that's already one hour ahead of UTC during the summer).

Comment: If you're just asking why the API data is calculated at different times in different locations: why wouldn't it be? I don't know where their source data comes from but it might have different sampling intervals, processing/aggregation, caching, ...

Comment: New York time is 18.54, Tokyo 07.51, Berlin 00.57 The minutes are different even though I search at the same time.

Comment: That just tells you the data is calculated at different times, it's unclear why you think that's a _problem_. The error in your code is `data.dt + data.timezone`, which doesn't make sense for the reason discussed above, but I don't think that's what you're even asking about.

Comment: I understand what you mean. My problem is that the minutes displayed do not match the actual time. I don't want to show the user's local time but the local time of the city I'm looking for weather for